# Kivy - Referencing IDs of Subclasses (Nested IDs)

Tags: python, android, kivy, kivy-language

I'm creating a kivy app right now. I'm quite new to Kivy and kv lang and there doesn't seam to be much rumour about it although i find it great to seperate code logic and layout, especially after some pygame development.
So to my actuall problem: I have a wiki-style screen for screenmanager, consisting out of a BoxLayout:

- Title as Label
- Scrollable Label for the Text (later , there shall be displayed a nested kv file)
- Buttons for Navigation (scroll up and go back to main screen)

Now I'm recreating the Navigation buttons to be floating type as known from many webpages and apps. Problem is, I suddendly cant reference my ScrollView anymore. Any help or suggestions?

```html
<Wiki>:
    name: "wiki"
    
    canvas.before:
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
            source: "picture.jpg"

    BoxLayout:
        id: box
        orientation: "vertical"
        padding: 10
        spacing: 10
    
        Label:
            font_size: 20
            size_hint_y: .1
            text: root.country_text    
            
        ScrollView:
            id: scrlvw
            BackgroundLabel:
                background_color: 220,220,220, 0.5
                size_hint_y: None
                text_size: self.width, None
                height: self.texture_size[1]
                halign: "left"
                valign: "top"
                text: root.wiki_text
        
        FloatLayout:
            size_hint_y: .1
            
            Button:
                size_hint_x: .2
                pos_hint: {"center_x": .25, "center_y": .5}
                text: "Back"
                on_release:
                    app.root.current = "main"
                    root.manager.transition.direction = "right"
                    
    FloatButton:
        size_hint_x: .2
        pos_hint: {"center_x": .75, "center_y": .5}
        text: "Up"
        on_release: 
            widget = BoxLayout()
            widget.ids.scrlvw.scroll_y = 0
```

Before, when it worked, it was:

```html
    BoxLayout:
        FloatLayout:
            size_hint_y: .1
            
            Button:
                size_hint_x: .2
                pos_hint: {"center_x": .25, "center_y": .5}
                text: "Back"
                on_release:
                    app.root.current = "main"
                    root.manager.transition.direction = "right"

            Button:
                size_hint_x: .2
                pos_hint: {"center_x": .75, "center_y": .5}
                text: "Up"
                on_release: 
                    scrlvw.scroll_y = 0
```

Well as its just a design question, I guess i temporary have to dismiss the floating design. But I would be so pleased if you could help me understand this language better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as the 'kv' code described as "when it worked" is still in the same `<Wiki>` rule, it should still work. The newer `kv` code will never work as you are trying to create a new `BoxLayout` and reference an `id` in it. That has two problems:

1. The newly created `BoxLayout` is not the `BoxLayout` instance that appears in your GUI, so any changes to it will have no effect on what appears in the display.
2. Unless you have a `<BoxLayout>` rule in your `kv`, the newly created `BoxLayout` will not have a `scrlvw` `id`.

The `ids` defined within a `kv` rule are available for use only within that rule. See the [documntation](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.lang.html#ids).

Comment: I see my mistake: So I have to put my `FloatButton` class within the `BoxLayout` rule because thats where `scrlvw` `id` is stored. I probably have to set a `FloatLayout` above the `Box Layout` rule so that the `FloatButton` won't mess with the design and find a way to set up an `on_release` event which works with the dynamic class. Thanks for your help.

Comment: So I reworked the code, removed my `FloatButton` dynamic class by a simple button class and everything worked just fine. Thanks